# Fibonacci in Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, fibonacci, modulo

For a given array, say, **[1, 2, 3]**, I am trying to calculate **(fib(1) + fib(2) + fib(3) + fib(1+2) + fib(2+3) + fib(1+2+3))%m**, where fib denotes Fibonacci number at given index and **m** is the modulo number.

Values of array can go upto **1000000000**. I can calculate **nth** fibonacci through matrix exponentiation in log(n) but how to perform the required addition process apart from **O(n*n)**.

Comment: What is this magic set of fib arguments?

Comment: are you looking for this: https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms?

Comment: it's summaton of fib(arr[i]+arr[i+1]+.....+arr[j]), where 1<=i<=j<=N, N is length of array, array is 1-indexed.

Comment: Summation of such sequence 1..3 contains 3 members, but your example contains 6 members

Comment: What is the patterns in the arguments to the the `fib` in the parentheses? Are they different consecutive integers of length `k`, or are they any set of distinct `k` integers chosen from the [1:n]?